# Foundation does not work

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, responsive

I am learning on how to make a canvas menu with Foundation & I made this example but it does not work at all!

Here's the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 9]>
<html class="lt-ie10" lang="en">
<![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>thenewboston</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="off-canvas-wrap" data-offcanvas>
        <div class="inner-wrap">

            <!-- Toggle button -->
            <a class="left-off-canvas-toggle" href="#">Toggle Menu</a>

            <!-- Offcanvas menu -->
            <aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
                <ul class="no-bullet">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </aside>

            <!-- Main content -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="medium-6 columns bg-2">Hey now dude</div>
                <div class="medium-6 columns bg-3">This is some sample content</div>
            </div>

            <!-- Exit overlay -->
            <a class="exit-off-canvas"></a>

        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).foundation();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Everything looks perfect and my `css` & `js` folders are correctly placed at the same directory. I also test if foundation works or not with another simple example and it worked fine. I really don't know why it's not working. Please if you know how to solve it ,please let me know.. Thanks!

Comment: nope! you're wrong..

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?